# split by delimiter only if it is followed by some string

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have a string `"values.component_category:monstor_client,dimensions.pool:rpool1,dimensions.env:prod,values.error_description:No content to map due to end-of-input↵ at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2ef452e5; line: 1, column: 1],values.incident_category:health"`

and trying to split it by `,` only if it is followed by string `values` or `dimensions`. Since there is another `,` in `; line: 1, column: 1` and I want to escape that.

I tried with regex `.split(/,?(values|dimensions)./)`

Expected output:

```
[
   "values.component_category:monstor_client",
   "dimensions.pool:rpool1", 
   "dimensions.env:pord", 
   "values.error_description:No content to map due to end-of java.io.StringReader@2ef452e5; line: 1, column: 1]", 
   "values.incident_category:health"
]
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: @Rahul I tried with `.split(/,?(values|dimensions)./)` like split by `,` only if it is followed by `values` or `dimensions`

Comment: you are missing a **g** flag at the end of your regex. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwnjkrqjs0a4vta/regex_delimiter.JPG?raw=1) is your solution

Comment: looks like I found the right regex `.split(/,(?=values|dimensions)/)`. This works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

In particular you need to use look-ahead, something like: `,(?=values|dimensions)`

Comment: I removed the braces and it works for me`/,(?=values|dimensions)/`

Comment: Ok, thank you for the feedback. I updated the answer. Feel free to mark it as correct, to point the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` and  `String.split()` to achieve this:

```js
var str =  "values.component_category:monstor_client,dimensions.pool:rpool1,dimensions.env:prod,values.error_description:No content to map due to end-of-input↵ at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2ef452e5; line: 1, column: 1],values.incident_category:health";

var arr = str.split(/,(?=values|dimensions)/);

var result = arr.reduce((a,val)=>{
  var key = val.substring(0, val.indexOf(":"));
  var value = val.substring(val.indexOf(":")+1)
  a[key] = value;
  return a;
},{});

console.log(result);
```